# How to change icon size in v-checkbox Vuetify 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify 3 in my Vue.js project and have implemented a v-checkbox component. However, I'm struggling to find a way to change the size of the checkbox icon. By default, the icon is quite large, and I'd like to make it small to better fit my design.

I've tried inspecting the CSS classes and the Vuetify documentation, but I can't seem to find any straightforward solution for modifying the icon size specifically for the v-checkbox component in Vuetify 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could [adjust the icon aliases](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#extending-available-aliases) for `checkboxOff`, `checkboxOn` and `checkboxIndeterminate`:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'

const checkboxAliases = ['checkboxOff', 'checkboxOn', 'checkboxIndeterminate']
checkboxAliases.forEach(alias => aliases[alias] += ' mdi-36px')

export default createVuetify({
  icons: {
    aliases
  },
})
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

;['checkboxOff', 'checkboxOn', 'checkboxIndeterminate'].forEach(alias => {
  vuetify.icons.aliases[alias] += ' mdi-36px'
})

createApp({}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-checkbox label="checkbox" />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```